# search Function not working properly laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've been learning laravel 5.2 recently and have a basic understanding of how laravel works, i've made a basic search function and want to search records from my database

This is my Search function within my ProductenController

```
 public function search(request $request)
{
    //searching for products by name
    Producten::where('naam', 'LIKE', '%$request->naam%');
    return redirect(route('producten.index')->with($request));

}
```

in the producten.index.blade i have my search

```
 {!! Form::open(['route' => 'producten.index', 'method' => 'GET', 'class' => 'search']) !!}

    {!! Form::text('naam')!!}

 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Also here are my Routs

```
Route::resource('producten', 'ProductenController', ['only' => ['index', 'store', 'delete', 'edit', 'update', 'create', 'search']]);
```

And this is the Model i want to search the records from.

```
class Producten extends Model
{

// model producten holdes the attribues naam, inkoopprijs, verkoopprijs, 

protected $fillable = ['Id', 'naam',' inkoopprijs', 'verkoopprijs', 'fabrieken_Id'];
protected $table = 'Producten';

public $timestamps = false;



}
```

if there is anythink i forgot to include for u to be able to help me just let me know

Comment: Can you explain what exactly mean not working properly?

Comment: when i search a product it doesn't show the product im searching for

Comment: Is it showing anything at all? Some error... or blank page?

Comment: Your code is entirely wrong, I don't know where to start.

Comment: i have the search bar within my product view so the text bar is above the products i displayed from the database, and when im searching for a product nothing happens

Comment: You think your queried products will magically go anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably lies in this line:

`Producten::where('naam', 'LIKE', '%$request->naam%');`

If you want to use inline variables use double quotes "
I also added curly brackets around it for readability.

```
Producten::where('naam', 'LIKE', "%{$request->naam}%");
```

Finally also make sure that you actually GET the content after using statements either by using ->get() or ->paginate()

```
 Producten::where('naam', 'LIKE', "%{$request->naam}%")->get();
```

Comment: Instead of downvoting, try to help him out by correcting at what he might be doing wrong. Just saying "your code is all wrong" doesn't add to it at all.

Comment: I don't think Stack Overflow is the best place to learn basics of things by requesting code fixes. If he doesn't know Laravel, then learn or skip it. Plus how this shitty question got upvotes, LOL.

Comment: I agree with you on that. Laracasts is one excellent place to start out.

Comment: I'd say the best thing to start is Laravel Documentation, which is decent enough to make it possible to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably lies in this line:

```
Producten::where('naam', 'LIKE', '%$request->naam%');
```

You should

```
Producten::where('naam', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->naam . '%');
```